# jquery remove not working on appended item

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to remove items I've added to a list i've added.

The script works on items that are in the list but not ones that gets appended.

http://jsfiddle.net/9mkmE/

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.add').click(function() {
    $(".list").append('<li>'
                              + 'Item '
                              + '<a href="#" class="remove_project_file" border="2">X</a>'
                              + '</li>');

    return false;
});

// using live() will bind the event to all future
// elements as well as the existing ones
$('.remove').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    return false;
});
});
</script>

<span class="inputname">
    <a href="#" class="add">
        Add
    </a>
</span>

<ul class="list">
    <li>Item <a href="#" class="remove" border="2">X</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Comment: The items you're adding to the list have class `remove_project_file` not class `remove`. You do still need to delegate to an element above the list items being added, as in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use .`on()`'s event delegation syntax:

Change:

```
$('.remove').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    return false;
});
```

to:

```
$('.list').on('click', '.remove', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    return false;
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/9mkmE/9/)**

Note that you also need to add the remove class to your appended list items:

```
$(".list").append('<li>' + 'Item ' + '<a href="#" class="remove remove_project_file" border="2">X</a>' + '</li>');
```

From the docs on [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().
>   To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event
>   binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the
>   HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page,
>   select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is
>   placed into the page.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the element on document ready before it has even been created. You need to bind to an element that is already present on page load. Change your JS to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click', '.add', function() {
        $(".list").append('<li>' + 'Item ' + '<a href="#" class="remove_project_file" border="2">X</a>' + '</li>');
    return false;
    });

    $('body').on('click', '.remove', function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just call `.bind()` on the element after creating it.